# Installing Windows 10 32-bit in virtual box not working

Tags: virtualbox, windows, 17.10

I'm trying to install Windows in Oracle virtualbox from a usb boot and it's stuck on this screen: 
[image]

What drivers would I need on the disk to work properly?

Comment: Actually this is one of those unmeasurably helpful but typical Windows errors that made me stop using Windows and Ubuntu instead. I fear we can't fight this from Ubuntu.

Comment: Luckily enough, I was able to download the .iso files for 32 and 64-bit from Microsoft so I'm able to install them that way. I'll see how it runs though. I'm switching mostly to Ubuntu too. There's some apps that I've done everything I can to install through wine in various ways, but I just need to Windows to run. I'm going to just run it virtually because Ubuntu is just too good for me not to have.

Comment: Other than Ubuntu Windows may need a driver for an USB-key. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By downloading the .iso files, I was able to install it that way. Booting the the usb was causing the issue.